# Aws VPN - Cisco ASA connect vpc with a single device behind cisco ASA

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, vpn, cisco, cisco-asa

I want to configure an IPsec VPN connection between Cisco ASA and AWS VPN. In this configuration, I want only one IP address, which is a machine behind Cisco ASA in AWS VPN.

Is it possible to set only one static IP in the static route of VPN connection for example (10.1.1.26/32) or do I need to specify the entire subnet?

Comment: *"In this configuration i must specify only one static ip"*  Why do you say this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is common to only allow one IP on the end of a VPN. We have several to allow remote support of particular servers.